# setInterval & Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched up and down and have yet to find something that will allow setInterval to work in any version of Internet Explorer.

Below is the code I am using right now...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#varRefresh').load('reload.php');

    window.setInterval("refreshVar();", 5000); //**** every 5 seconds
});

function refreshVar() {
    $('#varRefresh').load('reload.php');
}
</script>

<div id="varRefresh">
</div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can get it to work in IE?

Comment: 5000 != every 20 seconds

Comment: What seems to be the problem, besides the fact that `refreshVar()` is called every 5 seconds instead of 20?

Comment: `window.setInterval("refreshVar();", 5000);` - better do `window.setInterval(refreshVar, 5000);`. (More info on syntax: [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: F12 to open IE's error console. There's nothing in this code that should fail, but previous scripts may be erroring.

Answer (score 3):

The page you're trying to load may simply be cached.

You can force Internet Explorer not to cache pages as follows: 
[Prevent caching of pages in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11082256/1419007).

Alternatively, you may simply append a timestamp to the URL; because the URL is new to IE, it will always load the latest version.

#### Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#varRefresh').load('reload.php?'+new Date().getTime());

    window.setInterval(refreshVar, 5000); //**** every 5 seconds
});

function refreshVar() {
    $('#varRefresh').load('reload.php?'+new Date().getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
window.setInterval("refreshVar();", 5000);   //**** every 5 seconds
```

with this:

```
window.setInterval(refreshVar, 5000);   //**** every 5 seconds
```

(making the first argument a function reference instead of a string)

Comment: I tried this with no luck.

It does the .load portion just fine.  It just doesn't refresh every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BhT8M/) tested on Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Opera, Internet Explorer and android browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#varRefresh').load('reload.php');
    refreshVar();
});

function refreshVar() {
    var refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $('#varRefresh').load('reload.php');
    }, 5000);
}
</script>

<div id="varRefresh">
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the name of the function as a string literal, try passing the function as a reference like this:

```
window.setInterval(refreshVar, 5000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use setTimeout() instead. Look at this resource about it:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: I expected to find examples on that website `w3fools.com` meant by w3schools wrong information!

Comment: You shouldn't point anyone to that site.  If you change your answer, include an explanation that setTimeout will only fire once, and change that link to go to a reputable site, I'll vote your answer back up again.  That link does not explicitly state that setTimeout fires only once, either.  It's a bad website with bad information.